# JFileChooser shows invalid file size in detail view

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, windows-explorer, filechooser

Please refer to the image below and clarify me what is the root cause for this. While windows explorer shows correct file size, `JFileChooser` shows wrong size. 
I am telling file chooser is wrong because txt file is 0 byte file which I created, but file chooser shows 1kb for the same.

[image]

Comment: *"windows explorer shows correct file size"* Actually it doesn't. Right click on the file and 'show details' for the correct size.

Comment: yes, I did that as well, windows file properties shows it is 0 byte in both windows.

Comment: OK.. well the rest can be explained by 'rounding differences' in the last digit of '# of K'. This is fussing over trivialities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the size of the same file in each of the two listings differs by 1 KB. Windows includes the file's *metadata*, like they talk about [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111226-00/?p=8813), but `JFileChooser` includes just the [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length--) of the file's *content*.